# Why is my MSI uninstalling after installing?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I've created an MSI with Visual Studio 2010 using the Deployment Project template. It used to work, but now it has started acting up when installing over an earlier version - i.e. upgrading. I have set `RemovePreviousVersions` to true, but what is actually happening is that it removes "previous" version *after* installing the new version, effectively removing the *new* version also. In the [MSI log](http://pastebin.com/gY298hBN) file I see evidence of this. (Feel free to examine it)

Shouldn't normal installation procedure be to 1. uninstall previous version, 2. install new version? Anyone have any explanation of this?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2418919

Comment: I'm thoroughly impressed that you managed to nail the problem with that single link from my somewhat incomplete problem description :-) If you post that as an answer instead of comment I'll credit it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure whether it was a match but you indicated it was.  There's a bug in the VS2010 version of the Setup project feature that strikes when you moved the project from VS2008 to VS2010.  Quoting from the [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2418919):

> This problem occurs because a different hashing algorithm is used to create the GUIDs in Visual Studio 2010. When you install the MSI file that is created from the Visual Studio 2010 Setup project, the MSI file determines that the GUID has changed and removes the files and registry keys for the installation path based on the sequence of the project.
>
> In this scenario, the files and registry keys for the installation path disappear unexpectedly.

There's a hotfix for it, follow the KB article link for the download and the usage instructions.

Comment: It was indeed the problem, as I had upgraded the .sln file from 2008 to 2010 recently. It didn't cross my mind that that was relevant though. Glad I "only" wasted 2 hours on this problem before reaching out for help.

Comment: FWIW, that project type has been removed from VS 2012.  It's likely that all your time on it is wasted.  That tool is horrible as it so poorly abstracts the developer from Windows Installer that it doesn't even expose the concept of a component.